# Prevent UNDOTBS to abort import

Tags: oracle, import

I have a dumpfile that I want to import in an Oracle 10g database in a virtual machine (with limited disk space). The dump file is about 3.5GB.

When I try to import the dump, the size of the `UNDOTBS01.DBF` file explodes (up to 12GB – stopped because the disk was full).

I tried the following with no luck:

- lower the `undo_retention` value
- switch `undo_management` to `MANUAL`
- switch the `AUTORESIZE` property of the `UNDOTBS01` tablespace to `OFF`

I read that the undo tablespace was used for flashbacks and rollbacks, I don't need any of these, I just want the data of the dump into the database.

What can I do?

Comment: Which import utility are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Undo function is to provide oracle with "past" versions of the data.
Don't switch undo management to manual, it will make things worse, as you will have to manage the rollback segments by hand.

What should work is to remove autoextend from the undo datafiles. Set the undo total space higher that is normal usage. The undo will fill 100% and will oracle will begin reusing it.

That can have consequences, like transactions failing with snapshot too old errors, so be careful in a production enviroment.